# Sumar datos de un array en el controlador - Laravel

Tags: php

Hola puedo sumar estos datos en mi controlador??

Mi variable se llama `$beneficio`

```
array:12 [▼
  "2019-Nov" => 0
  "2019-Dec" => 0
  "2020-Jan" => 0
  "2020-Feb" => 0
  "2020-Mar" => 0
  "2020-Apr" => 0
  "2020-May" => 0
  "2020-Jun" => 0
  "2020-Jul" => 0
  "2020-Aug" => 0
  "2020-Sep" => 0
  "2020-Oct" => 29.5055
]
```

Aunque ahora sean cero los demás meses, que sume por 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usando la funcion `array_sum` de PHP se puede hacer eso, tomando tu variable `$beneficio`, seria asi

```
$res = array_sum($beneficio)
```

Referencia:

- [array_sum](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.array-sum.php)

Comment: Aunque te recomiendo investigar mas y cuando aun asi no encuentres respuestas, preguntar seria tu ultima opcion

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta! @JuanRivera . Siempre consulto todo y pruebo todo antés de preguntar. Lo que ya hoy es un día colapsado de averiguar cosas y por eso pregunte, gracias!